# Retrieving details of Test object

Tags: c#, hp-quality-center, test-plan

After reading the folderstructure of `QC Test Plan`, I have read a list of `Test`
by

```
TestFactory testFactory = (TestFactory)qcConnection.TestFactory;
TDFilter testFilter = (TDFilter)testFactory.Filter;

TDAPIOLELib.List testList;

folderPath = folderPath.Trim();
testFilter["TS_SUBJECT"] = "\"" + folderPath + "\"";

testList = (List) testFactory.NewList(testFilter.Text);

foreach (Test testItem in testList)
{
    //.... 
}
```

The above code works. I can read Test ID, Name, and some more simple fields.

As can be seen in this picture

[image: qc test]

There is a "description" page on the bottom of the "details" page.

How can I retrieve values from it? How can I reach those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description text as per your diagram can be accessed using:

```
myString = testItem("TS_DESCRIPTION")
```

or

```
myString = testItem.Field("TS_DESCRIPTION")
```

The result is basically HTML of everything in that Description tab.